# Problem with UIBarButton Localization

Tags: iphone, ios, localization

```
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(sendRequest)];
    [[[self navigationBar] topItem] setRightBarButtonItem:button];
    [button release];
```

According to apple documentation, it's supposed to be localized. But when I turn m app to french, it's still in english: 'Done'. Do you know what I am missing ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do test **on a real device**: I already had such issues with localization on the simulator (only on UIBarButtonItems and framework-embed controls like this, not on custom localized strings).

Changing **the localization of the simulator sometimes seems not to be taken into account**, especially for framework-provided strings like the default title of the back or done button or such, whereas it does work as expected on a real device.

*(Also, I suggest you also set your `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` key in the Info.plist to French, that couldn't hurt)*

Answer (score 1):

Set the

```
Localization native development region
```

key in your info.plist to your region (fr).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try "Clean and Build" after changing the setting in simulator, or try deleting the application file of your program from, yoursystem->Library->Application support->iphone simulator->4.3.2->Application , try deleting those files and run.

Incase it still doesn't work, There is a good  tutorial for this purpose http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial